# Optimizing a nested for-loop using CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

So I have a project I'm working on that uses OpenCV to detect motion in moving objects. I'm trying to speed up the detection and have a nested for-loop that I want to speed up using CUDA. I have CUDA integration all set up in Visual Basic. Here is the nested for-loop in my .cpp file.

```
      for (int i=0; i<NumberOfFeatures; i++)
  {
    // Compute integral image.
    cvIntegral(mFeatureImgs[i], mFirstOrderIIs[i]);

    for (int j=0; j<NumberOfFeatures; j++)
    {
      // Compute product feature image.
      cvMul(mFeatureImgs[i], mFeatureImgs[j], mWorker);

      // Compute integral image.
      cvIntegral(mWorker, mSecondOrderIIs[i][j]);
    }
  }
```

I'm relatively new to CUDA, so my question is, could someone show me an example of how exactly I would make this nested for-loop go faster using CUDA?

Comment: have you considered using OpenCV gpu module?

Comment: These are the similar questions that has been already answered. You may find your answer in them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479715/nested-loops-to-cuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9921873/for-nested-loops-with-cuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306117/cuda-kernel-nested-for-loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420345/nested-kernels-in-cuda

Answer (score 2):

As sgar91 pointed out, OpenCV includes a GPU module as described here:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU

That wiki also suggests how to ask GPU related questions on the OpenCV help forum on Yahoo.

There is a gpu-accelerated image integral function.  If you look around you may find an equivalent for cvMul as well.

you can't use the exact same datatypes in the non-GPU code and the GPU version.  Take a look at the "short sample" example given on the wiki page I posted previously.  You will see you need to do something like this to transfer your existing data to data structures that can be operated on by the GPU:

```
    cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;  // this is defining variables that can be accessed by the GPU
    src.upload(src_host);      // this is loading the src (GPU variable) with the image data

    cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);  //this is causing the GPU to act
```

you will need to do someting similar, such as:

```
    cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
    src.upload(src_data);

    cv::gpu::integral(src, dst);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert, I asked there before coming to StackOverflow actually. Still no response and it's been 2 days. Any suggestions on how I get this OpenCV GPU module running for the integral? When i switch cvIntegral to cv::gpu::integral it gives me a parameter error because i don't have something called gpu::mat?

Answer (score 1):

cv_integral basically sums up pixel values along both dimensions - this can be done with matrix operations only. So if you like, you can also try arrayfire for that.
I created you a small example how to do image manipulations using matrices:

```
// computes integral image
af::array cv_integral(af::array img) {

  // create an integral image of size + 1
  int w = img.dims(0), h = img.dims(1);
  af::array integral = af::zeros(w + 1, h + 1, af::f32);

  integral(af::seq(1,w), af::seq(1,h)) = img;

  // compute inclusive prefix sums along both dimensions
   integral = af::accum(integral, 0);
   integral = af::accum(integral, 1);

   std::cout << integral << "\n";

   return integral;
}

void af_test()
{
 int w = 6, h = 5; // image size
 float img_host[] = {5,2,3,4,1,7,
                    1,5,4,2,3,4,
                    2,2,1,3,4,45,
                    3,5,6,4,5,2,
                    4,1,3,2,6,9};

  //! create a GPU image (matrix) from the host data
  //! NOTE: column-major order!!
  af::array img(w, h, img_host, af::afHost);

   //! create an image from random data
   af::array img2 = af::randu(w, h) * 10;
   // compute integral images
   af::array integral = cv_integral(img);
   // elementwise product of the images
   af::array res = integral * img2;
   //! compute integral image
   res = cv_integral(res);
   af::eval(res);
   std::cout << res << "\n";
}
```